# iOS Remote Notification with System Sound

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

[This page in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH39-SW1) says:

> A custom or **system-provided** sound can accompany any of the other three notification types.

But I can't find anywhere how to specify a system-provided sound. How do I do this? I want to use one of Apple's built-in sounds in iOS besides the default "tri-tone" one. I've already tried putting in the names of some of the system sounds, and that didn't work. I know how to put custom sounds in, but I don't want to copy an iOS sound file into my app because of copyright.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714377/non-main-bundle-file-as-alert-sound 
Here, this question is answered beautifully, please refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**system-provide** sound refers to the use of `default` as the value of `sound` in your aps dictionary. Otherwise it's the name of a sound file in the app bundle or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container.

Answer (score 2):

What that document means to say is that you can provide your own custom sound or let the system choose the default notification sound based on the users settings.  You can't pick which system sound unless you download that audio file and include it yourself.