# System sound on push

Tags: ios, push-notification, push, ios10

In my app user can select sound for push-notification. I got all system sounds from "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds", but the problem is when I'm setting another system sound as sound for push-notification default sound playing. Can I set another system sound as push sound? Or I should pass id of that sound? Or maybe I can use only custom sounds?

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Helped for me. Copying sound to folder available from Backend solve this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624018/4911483